# Internet Explorer 9 VHD

Tags: internet-explorer-9

When trying to test across multiple versions of Internet Explorer (6, 7, 8) I have in the past used the Virtual PC Console and mounted VHDs available from Microsoft. I am running Windows Server 2003.

This system seems to suit me, although now IE9 is on the scene I wondered if anyone knew of a VHD for the IE9 beta?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What I've had to do is download the [IE8 Vista VHD](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyId=21EABB90-958F-4B64-B5F1-73D0A413C8EF&displaylang=en) and manually update it to the latest IE9 beta.

Edit: You can also sign up for a [90 day trial of Windows 7](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/evalcenter/cc442495) (and update manually to IE9). Seems to run better for me than Vista, but you have to sign up (free) for their Developer Network). There may be ways to extend the 90 day trial if you Google a bit.

Edit 2: MS have just updated the [IE VHD page](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=21eabb90-958f-4b64-b5f1-73d0a413c8ef&displaylang=en) with *details* for IE9 (Vista & Win7) but I can't see the updated download links yet. I guess they'll be there pretty soon.

Edit 3 (Thanks to brillyfresh): **The [IE VHD page](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=21eabb90-958f-4b64-b5f1-73d0a413c8ef&displaylang=en) now has a VM for IE9 available to download.**

Edit 4: There isn't currently a VM for IE10, but you can either manually install IE10 in the Windows 7 / IE9 VM or you can download a [90 day Windows 8 evaluation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/evalcenter/jj554510.aspx).

Comment: IE9 download links are now included on that page, although it includes tools that make the full download package quite heavier. The IE8 package has an installation file for IE9 (guest path is C:\Internet Explorer Versions\IE9-Windows7-x86-enu.exe), so if you're aiming to save some bandwidth and hard drive space, just download the IE8 image and install IE9 from there.

Comment: I'm running these in Ubuntu with VirtualBox, which supports snapshots. I'm not sure if VirtualPC has these but it enables you to get the IE8 one, save a snapshot then install IE9, allowing you to easily switch between the 2.

Comment: That's similar to the approach I use, also Ubuntu VBox; I save a snapshot before running the Vista/7 VM for the first time. That way when the activation period expires (and/or rearm is used up), I can restore the original snapshot and have a fresh activation period again, minus Guest Additions and any other software that I installed, but if you're using these VHDs for IE testing specifically, you probably won't have any extra software installed besides Guest Additions and IE9 anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Have you look at SuperPreview in Expression Web?  http://expression.microsoft.com/en-us/dd565874.aspx I don't think IE9 is included, but it may improve your productivity.

I am not aware of a VHD with an OS and IE9, but there isn't any reason you couldn't create one.

Comment: The actual download links on that SuperPreview page lead to a dead page on Microsoft's website.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft is releasing "Platform Previews" of IE9 that can be installed side-by-side with IE8 on Windows Vista and Windows 7, so there's no need to use a virtual machine. http://ie.microsoft.com/testdrive/

Comment: Apologies, I should have said.  I'm using Windows Server 2003, so cannot run the preview...

Comment: The IE9 Platform Preview appears to now be gone, replaced by an alpha of IE10 - so much for testing IE9 side-by-side. Anyone have a link to an IE9 that CAN be installed side-by-side?

Answer (score 0):

http://modern.ie/en-us/virtualization-tools#downloads

images for linux (virtual box),mac  and windows  to test ie 6-11