# Run Internet Explorer 9 on Windows Xp Professional for testing purposes?

Tags: windows-xp, internet-explorer-9

I want to test my web application on Internet Explorer 9 but I don't want to buy a copy of Vista/Win 7 on my developer machine with Windows XP.

Anyone knows a workaround, free and easy?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use another machine.

Or better, get a set of Virtual Machines established which have an array of operating systems and browsers installed.  Build enough VMs, and you are covered for all eventualities, regardless of whether you would personally use them or not.

[Link to Internet Explorer Application Compatibility VirtualPC Images](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=11575)

Comment: Using Virtual Machines would still require buying a Vista/Win7 license.

Comment: Granted, but there are all kinds of schemes that MS offers to get operating systems cheaply.  I can run 10 copies of any MS OS for the grand total of 240UKP.

Long and short of it is, you wanna test your site on IE9 - there's no substitute for an actual working copy of IE9.

Comment: Moreover partly solution of this problem could be found here: [Internet Explorer 9 VHD](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3363572/internet-explorer-9-vhd/4472988#4472988)

Answer (score 7):

You can't.  The closest you'll get is IE9Preview.

I've found that [IETester](http://www.my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/) is not a bad way to quickly switch between browser versions for testing.

Comment: Yes, but does IE9Preview work with Windows XP? And second question: How to get IE9Preview? Now it is only IE10Preview available, and it doesn't work with Windows XP.

Comment: IETester works with backward compatibility so that you can't run ie9 or ie10 in xp as well.

Answer (score 2):

http://wiki.winehq.org/WineOnWindows
You can try running Wine on windows.
This will let you emulate a newer version of Windows
However, it will be really buggy (not mentioning how Wine is already buggy)
Its a unix/linux application ported for Windows
:)

Comment: My god, a Windows API ported to the Unix API ported to an older Windows API! +1 for the sheer madness involved.

Answer (score 0):

IE 7,8,9

https://browserlab.adobe.com

Comment: -1 for need to create the AdobeID account.
-1 for that you cannot test your websites on localhost.
-1 for run veeeery slowly.

Comment: -1 for no longer accurate (only IE 9 is supported), the need for your code to be in production before you can test it, and restricted access that prevents you from debugging JS or DOM.

Answer (score 0):

Use

https://browserling.com

In unpaid version you have 3 minutes to test any site accessed from Internet on any browser.

In paid version you have unlimited sessions and ssh tunneling.